# Question about ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App />)

Tags: reactjs

I am following the course of Full stack. https://fullstackopen.com/en/part1/introduction_to_react

It uses `npx create-react-app part1` to create a example react project.

So for this statement in index.js
`ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App />)` 
the course says that `document.getElementById('root'))` is using the content defined in the file public/index.html, having the id value 'root'.

So I wonder if we can modify something in the index.html to influence what will show in the result of web application. I tried but failed with no influence.

The corresponding part of "public/index.html, having the id value 'root'." is defined as following:
`<div id="root"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

You can modify everything in the `index.html`.

Entire content of `<div id="root"></div>` will just be replaced with the React app.

Comment: Yeah, but when i tried to replace  `<div id="root"></div>`  with 
```<div id="root">
      <p> 2313212</p>
    </div>
```
then the result remain the same. So why could this happen?

Comment: **Entire content of <div id="root"></div> will just be replaced with the React app.**